# Using Charles Debugging with Chrome gives me 1-3% "Connection timed out"

Tags: google-chrome, connection-timeout, charles-proxy

At my job, we use the debugging tool Charles Proxy a lot. So I always have it running in the background. Sometimes it's recording, other times it's not.
However, lately it has started acting up. For every web request I do, there is a 1-3% chance that it will fail to connect with the reason: "Connect: Connection timed out: connect"

**Test case**
I did a test with Charles: Use the 'repeat advanced' option on a file to fetch it 50 times:
[image: Two of the 50 requests failed]

As you can see, 2 of them failed. (And it took it 21 seconds to timeout). The 98 other times, it took ~4ms to complete the request.

I did the same test with Charles closed and Fiddler opened instead.
After 400 requests of the file, not a single one had failed.

**Happens on normal usage**
Here, it happened when I opened the company game site. A rather important request failed and thus, the site never fully loaded.
[image]

**I have tried**
I tried restarting my computer.
I tried updating to the newest version of Charles.
I tried uninstalling and installing Charles.
I tried disconnecting from the VPN we're on.

I tried closing down Charles and that seems to fix it. But I need to have Charles running and I don't want to open and close it all the time.
I tried using Firefox instead of Chrome and it seemed to happen very rarely or almost never. However Firefox is really bad to use when working with Flash.

**Edit (Chrome net-internals)**
I logged the output from `chrome://net-internals/#events` when trying to load a file that failed.
Pastebin dumps: `http://pastebin.com/dgMaLMKc` then `http://pastebin.com/dAGpJCJy`

Comment: Has Chrome always been like that, or is it a recent regression? Have you already checked the output in `chrome://net-internals/#events` for anomalies?

Comment: It only recently started doing it more or less 2 months ago now. Before that, I had no trouble with it. 
I also posted pastebin links to events that failed in chrome.

Comment: Have you tried [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html)? If yes, and the bug is still reproducible, can you run a bisect to find out when the bug started showing up in Chrome? http://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py

Comment: I have having issues with Charles Proxy no longer working with breakpoints or throttling when connection timeout on a request. I have to shut it down then start it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem this was caused by the program `Ad Muncher`. After closing it down, the timed out connections has apparently stopped.